# How to migrate packages or find URL of packages?

Tags: appexchange, migration

I have some managed packages installed in my ORG, but as we are migrating from previous ORG to new ONE, is it possible to migrate packages as well?

Or how can I find appexchange URL for those packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is SF assisting you with the migration? If so they could be able to migrate the app a well.

Otherwise a search of AppExchange or contacting the vendor would be your bet bet